# Cannot connect to MQTT server with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, mqtt

I am just starting with Android Studio and have followed a YouTube video, but I keep failing to connect to the MQTT server. There are 16 errors in the Gradle build. I don't know where the problems are. How can I connect to the MQTT server?

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MqttDefaultFilePersistence$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MqttDefaultFilePersistence$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 5.816 secs
Information:17 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Here is my code

```
package com.example.leejunwen.newmqtt;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static String MQTTHOST = "test.mosquitto.org:1883";

    MqttAndroidClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
        client =new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), MQTTHOST, clientId);

        try {
            IMqttToken token = client.connect();
            token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    // We are connected
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    // Something went wrong e.g. connection timeout or firewall problems
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"connection fail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.leejunwen.newmqtt"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/"
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.2'
    compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2'
}
```

Here is my AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.leejunwen.newmqtt">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hi Lee, seems that the library is compiled in an old format. Are you importing Gradle dependencies in your Android Studio project like Paho suggest in this link? That will use the latest appropiate versions for Android. [Paho Android](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed the Gradle dependencies to the link that you suggested. I update the errors and add in the build.gradle. Now I can't build the APK.